# django group by aggregation on different choice field

Tags: django, django-orm

i have following table,

```
Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    account_type = models.CharField(choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE, max_length=30)


Ledger(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='ledger')
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=4, default=0.00)
    balance_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

In mention , Account types are ,

```
ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
(0, 'Asset'),
(1, 'Liabilities'),
(2, 'Equity'),
(3, 'Income'),
(4, 'Expense')
)
```

for example ,

In *Ledger* model, data are stored like this,

```
Account Name    Account Type   balance
------------    -------------  -------
sales           Income         400
Home expense    Expense        300
gross income    Income         100
staff salary    Expense        700
sales revenue   Income         300
Electric Bill   Expense        900
```

i want to get total balance of all `Income` and `Expense` type account separately within a date range.

to do so, i have trid as following,

```
if request.method == 'GET':

    start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
    end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')
    accounts = Account.objects.filter(Q(account_type=3) | Q(account_type=4))

    income = Ledger.objects.filter(
        account__in=accounts,
        balance_date__gte=start_date,
        balance_date__lte=end_date
    ).aggregate(Sum('balance'))

    serializer = LedgerSerializer(income, many=True)
    print serializer.data

    return Response(serializer.data})
```

but its returning a **empty orderdict**, i am assuring that i have data within the date range i am passing, if i remove the `aggregation` part from the above query , its return all the `Income` and `Expense` data without having total balance, which is logical but when i add `aggregation` part, its returns

```
[OrderDict()]
```

i am relatively new in django orm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that this query

```
income = Ledger.objects.filter(
    account__in=accounts,
    balance_date__gte=start_date,
    balance_date__lte=end_date
).aggregate(Sum('balance'))
```

doesn't return queryset but dictionary which you're trying to serialize. Perhaps you could first have query like this

```
income = Ledger.objects.filter(
account__in=accounts,
balance_date__gte=start_date,
balance_date__lte=end_date
)
```

then you serialize it

`serializer = LedgerSerializer(income, many=True)`

and finally call aggregate method

`total_balance = income.aggregate(Sum('balance'))`

The last thing you'll need is to return both variables in your response (e.g in a dictionary)